# I want scrollable in <thread> in table on top header

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

```
<div className="table-responsive">
<table className="table table-sm">
         <thead>
                  <tr className="table-active">
                      <th>name</th>
                      <th>nickname</th>
                      <th>age</th>
                      <th>gender</th>
                      <th>height</th>
                      <th>weight</th>
                  </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="table-body">
                  <tr>
                    <td>Alex</td>
                    <td>Alex</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>Male</td>
                    <td>1.70</td>
                    <td>60</td>
                  <tr>
         </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

i want css style scrollable in header table and under table and don't want fixed head table on top
so i was searching all day in google I can't found result i want please tell or help me.

Comment: There is no point in keeping the thead scrolling... I guess you want tbody scrolling?

Comment: explain your question in brief.

Comment: I want scroll <thread> and  <tbody> together